# Proving $\int_{I} f \geq 0$ for an integrable function that is positive at rationals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $I$ be a generalized rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and suppose $f  :I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable. Suppose $f(x) \geq 0$ if $x$ is a point in $I$ with a rational component. Prove $\int_{\mathbf{I}} f \geq 0$ holds.

---

My try:

By the integrability of $f$,

$$\begin{align*} \int_{\mathbf{I}} f &= \text{sup}\{L(f, \mathbf{P}) \mid \mathbf{P} \text{ is a partition of the generalized rectangle } \mathbf{I}\} \\
&= \text{inf}\{U(f, \mathbf{P}) \mid \mathbf{P} \text{ is a partition of the generalized rectangle } \mathbf{I}\} \end{align*}.$$

Since $f(x) \geq 0$ if a component of $x$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$, for any partition $\mathbf{P} = (P_1, P_2 \ldots, P_k)$ and generalized rectangle $J$, we get

$$U(f, P_{k}) = \text{sup}\{f(x) \mid x \in J\} \cdot \text{vol } \mathbf{J} \geq 0.$$

So $\text{inf}\{U((f, P)\}, \text{sup}\{L((f, P)\} \geq 0$

and result follows.

---

Is my proof orrect?

Comment: Are you talking about **Riemann** integrability?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, obviously.

Comment: How is your function defined at irrationals? On a different note, you may want to look at (Thomae's function)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function], which is integrable. The same argument can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user5325 For the exercise it does not matter how $f$ is defined at irrationals.

Comment: The Lord Shark comment is key.  My first impression was "but this is false!" because of the case $n=1$, $I=[0,1]$, and the function $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
1 &\mbox{ if $x$ is rational} \\
-1  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: @amsmath, if you dont know how the function is defined at irrationals, then how can you conclude that $\inf$ is also non-negative?

Comment: @user5325 The inf of non-negative numbers is also non-negative.

Comment: +wutv1922 Your proof is completely correct.

Comment: @user5325 : I believe that the assumption that the function is "Riemann integrable" implies that the upper and lower sums are the same in the limit.  So it suffices to only pay attention to the upper sums. I actually don't remember the definition of "Riemann integral" and was completely unable to determine its precise definition due to the wordiness of the wikipedia page on that topic (Ex: "Loosely speaking, the Riemann integral is the limit of the Riemann sums of a function"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral

Comment: But you should write $U(f,P) = \sum_{j=1}^k\sup\{f(x) : x\in P_k\}\cdot vol(P_k)\ge 0$, hence $\int_If = \inf_P U(f,P)\ge 0$.

Comment: @Michael The german page is better. ;-)

Comment: @Michael, thanks for pointing out! I agree that $\inf$ is non-negative. But in that case by definition of **Riemann integral**, value of the integral is the limit of upper sums (which are equal to lower sums) and since each upper sum is $\geq 0$, the limit will be $\geq 0$.

Comment: @amsmath : Somehow that is not surprising: I assume they efficiently get to the point!

Comment: @Michael Usually I prefer the english site. So no, in general this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as you have rightly pointed out, for any partition, $P$, the upper sum and lower sums are equal and upper sum is non-negative. Thus,
$$\int_I f = \lim_{\|P\|\to 0} \mathcal{U}(P,f).$$
Since each term in the limit is non-negative, the limit is non-negative. Hence $$\int_I f \geq 0.$$

Comment: Somebody needs reputation points? ;-)

Comment: Its already in the comments above. Whats a point in writing this as a separate answer?